# Best way to apply shader offscreen

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I'm investigating in the past few days what is the best way to apply OpenGl shader over some images, offscreen, and to save the results as files in the sdcard. All of that should be in the background and the user shouldn't notice it.

I came across two possible solutions: 
EGL(no documentation and all samples don't compile)
RenderBuffer, to create a FBO in OpenGl, assign renderBuffer to the FBO and draw explicitlly into it, the problem is that I'm allways getting "glError 1280" in the marked line, and also I'm confuse whether or not I can do all of that without glSurfaceView(as I said, I want it to be in the background).

I encountered in the HelloEfect darkroom sample in the Android SDK and did the following changes:

```
private void loadFrameBuffers(int tex) throws Exception {
    // creating FBO object
    int[] frame = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, frame, 0);
    int fboId = frame[0];
    TextureRenderer.checkGlError("glGenFramebuffers");
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);
    TextureRenderer.checkGlError("glBindFramebuffer");

    // // attaches texture to framebuffer - We need to attached RenderBuffer
    // image and not texture image!!!
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
            GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
    TextureRenderer.checkGlError("glFramebufferTexture2D");

    // creating RenderBuffer object
    int[] renderbuffers = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, renderbuffers, 0);
    TextureRenderer.checkGlError("glGenRenderbuffers");
    GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffers[0]);
    TextureRenderer.checkGlError("glBindRenderbuffer");

    int width = Math.min(GLES20.GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE, mImageWidth);
    int height = Math.min(GLES20.GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE, mImageHeight);

    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, 
            GLES20.GL_RGBA , width, height);
    TextureRenderer.checkGlError("glRenderbufferStorage"); // !!!!! throws exception


    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
            GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,
            renderbuffers[0]);
    TextureRenderer.checkGlError("glFramebufferRenderbuffer");

    int status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        throw new Exception("error in creating fbo, error code is: "
                + status);
}

private void loadTextures() {
    // Generate textures
    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);

    // Load input bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.puppy);
    mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

    // Upload to texture
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Set texture parameters
    GLToolbox.initTexParams();
}

 @Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if (!mInitialized) {
        // Only need to do this once
        mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
        mTexRenderer.init();
        loadTextures();
        try {
            loadFrameBuffers(mTextures[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mInitialized = true;
    }
    if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
        // if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
        initEffect();
        applyEffect();
    }
    renderResult();
}
```

the lines:
    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, 
                GLES20.GL_DEPTH_RANGE, width, height);
        TextureRenderer.checkGlError("glRenderbufferStorage");

throws "hlError 1280" exception and I cannot find what is the problem. Any help would be much appriciated!

Comment: 1280 means invalid enum. You are most likely passing an argument that is not meant to that parameter.

GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if
 target is not GL_RENDERBUFFER.GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if
 internalformat is not an accepted format.GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if 
 width or height is less than zero
 or greater than GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE.GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY is generated if the implementation is
 unable to create a data store with the requested 
 width and height.GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the reserved
 renderbuffer object name 0 is bound.

Comment: My guess is you must pass GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 instead of GL_DEPTH_RANGE, which does not make any sense

Comment: @Jean-Simon Brochu Thank for your reply, and I'll check it for sure, about the GL_DEPTH_RANGE, I putted it by mistake in stack overflow, actually I used GL_RGBA